How to find line is from the intersection point is positioned as left right down or upward direction using the co-ordinates
I am trying to find out the line position using the coordinates. I have two lines connected with each other using StartX,StartY, EndX & EndY.
Next, I have to figure it out direction of the second line (Right, Left, Up, Down). I tried this script but, getting some unexpected results.
Here x1 is startX, y1 is startY
x2 is endX, y2 is endY for the line 1
x3 is startX, y3 is startY
x4 is endX, y4 is endY for the line 2
export const getPositionOfPipe = ( x1: number, y1: number, x2: number, y2: number, x3: number, y3: number, x4: number, y4: number ): string => {
    
    if(  y4 - y2 > 0 ){
        return "Up"
    }
    if( y4 - y2 < 0 ){
        return "Down"
    }
    if( x4 - x2 >= 0 ){
        return "Right"
    }

    if( x4 - x2 <= 0 ){
        return "Left"
    }

    return "Parallel"
}


export const getPositionOfPipe = (
    x1: number, y1: number,
    x2: number, y2: number,
    x3: number, y3: number,
    x4: number, y4: number
): string => {
    const dx = x4 - x2;
    const dy = y4 - y2;

    const horizontal = dx > 0 ? "Right" : (dx < 0 ? "Left" : "");
    const vertical = dy > 0 ? "Up" : (dy < 0 ? "Down" : "");

    if (horizontal && vertical) {
        return `${vertical} ${horizontal}`;
    } else if (horizontal) {
        return horizontal;
    } else if (vertical) {
        return vertical;
    } else {
        return "No Movement";
    }
};

